# Implementing a POCO editor split over a number of TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am currently working on a project which uses the MVVM pattern. I have a POCO which I want to present in an editor and, because the object is composed from a number of smaller, reusable POCOs, I thought it would be appropriate to show it in a `TabControl`.

The result looks like this:

[image: Picture=1k words]

On the left is a collection of `ProductViewModel` and on the right is an instance of `ProductEditorViewModel`.

The editor splits the `Product` properties into groups - all of which have one or more View/ViewModel pairs. Each ViewModel has an `IsDirty` property to indicate its' edited status and an `IsEditable` property which defines whether the content can be edited or not.

What I am finding that it is tricky to get all the ViewModels properly linked together so that the `IsEditable` status gets passed down into nested ViewModels and that the `IsDirty` property gets passed up so that, for example, the `Save` button can be enabled.

I'm trying to keep it all as loose as possible. In the right of the picture is a list of Events with associated Actions. The selected MessageAction (see screen-shot) can itself define lists of Actions which are editable (in a separate dialog window). It can get quite complicated!

Any suggestions appreciated.

Here are some snippets:

**At top level**

```
    #region COMMAND - EditProductCommand
    private ICommand _EditProductCommand;
    public ICommand EditProductCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._EditProductCommand == null)
            {
                this._EditProductCommand = new RelayCommand(parm => DoEditProductCommand(), parm => CanDoEditProductCommand());
            }
            return this._EditProductCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanDoEditProductCommand()
    {
        // can only edit if editor, owner of product and editor not already in use
        return (app.CurrentUser.HasRole(Role.ProductEditor)) 
            && SelectedProduct != null
            && ProductEditorVM.IsDirty == false 
            && (SelectedProduct.Product.CheckedOutBy == null    // not checked out
            || SelectedProduct.Product.CheckedOutBy.UserGuid == app.CurrentUser.UserGuid);  // or owner
    }

    private void DoEditProductCommand()
    {
        if (SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.IsCheckedOut == false)
        {
            CheckoutCommand.Execute(null);
        }
        ProductEditorVM.EditProduct = SelectedProduct.Product;
        ProductEditorVM.IsEditable = true;
    }
    #endregion
```

**ProductEditorView**

```
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0">
        <TabItem Header="{x:Static me:Messages.Tab_Product_Core}">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CoreEditorVM}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="{x:Static me:Messages.Tab_Product_Events}">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding EventTreeVM}" 
                            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </TabItem>
```

**ProductEditorViewModel**

```
public class ProductEditorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IApplicationManager app;
    private static log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    #region PROPERTIES - SELECTED PRODUCT
    private IProduct _EditProduct;
    public IProduct EditProduct
    {
        get { return _EditProduct; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _EditProduct)
            {
                _EditProduct = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EditProduct");
                InitialiseProduct(_EditProduct);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region PROPERTIES - CORE
    private ProductCoreEditorViewModel _CoreEditorVM;
    public ProductCoreEditorViewModel CoreEditorVM
    {
        get { return _CoreEditorVM; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _CoreEditorVM)
            {
                _CoreEditorVM = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CoreEditorVM");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    [... and more ...]

    #region CONSTRUCTOR
    public ProductEditorViewModel(IApplicationManager app)
    {
        this.app = app;
        CoreEditorVM = new ProductCoreEditorViewModel();
        EventTreeVM = new ActionTreeViewModel(app);
        HistoryVM = new HistoryViewModel(app);

        CoreEditorVM.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(VM_PropertyChanged);
        EventTreeVM.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(VM_PropertyChanged);
    }


    private void InitialiseProduct(IProduct product)
    {
        CoreEditorVM.Initialise(product);
        EventTreeVM.Initialise(product.Events.EventList);
        HistoryVM.ItemsList = product == null ? null : app.PersistenceManager.GetProducts(
                new ProductCriteria(app.CurrentUser, false).Add(ProductCriteria.HasId(product.ProductGuid)),
                false);

        IsDirty = false;
    }

    void VM_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsDirty")
        {
            UpdateDirty();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDirty()
    {
        IsDirty = CoreEditorVM.IsDirty || EventTreeVM.IsDirty; 
    }
    #endregion
```

**ViewModelBase**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    bool _isDirty;
    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get { return _isDirty; }
        set
        {
            if (value != IsDirty)
            {
                _isDirty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _IsEditable;
    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return _IsEditable; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _IsEditable)
            {
                _IsEditable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsEditable");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _result;
    public bool DialogResult
    {
        get { return _result; }
        set
        {
            _result = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DialogResult");
        }
    }

    [...and more]
```

Comment: I guess you're going to have to show a bit of code how your ViewModels or POCOs are structured.

Comment: @Abbas - code snippets ready for you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty good. Just a few little things:

- Command-related methods `CanDoXXXX` and `DoXXXX` would be better off named `CanExecuteXXXX` and `ExecuteXXXX` or `OnExecuteXXXX`.
- I would put the ViewModel properties `IsEditable` and `IsDirty` in some `IEditable` interface that applicable *ViewModels* implement. Looks like reusable stuff.
- Your VM is *tightly coupled* with your log provider - I'd wrap it with some `ILogger` interface which would be constructor-injected as needed.
- You're not always consistent with access modifiers: sometimes you *do* specify the default (`private void InitialiseProduct`), other times you leave it (`void VM_PropertyChanged`). I'd specify it everywhere (be *explicit*).
- `IApplicationManager` is dangerous. You're passing it as a dependency which is good, but its name (`xxxxManager`) suggests that it might, over time, become a *shove-it-all-in-there* helper class with *low cohesion*. You don't show much code, but if all it's used for in the VM is to get the `app.CurrentUser`, maybe the VM's dependencies are more with some `ICurrentUser` than the whole `IApplicationManager`.
- Your `ViewModelBase` doesn't show its `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation, I'd do [something like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30769/converting-between-data-and-presentation-types) so instead of `OnPropertyChanged("CoreEditorVM")` you could do `OnPropertyChanged(() => CoreEditorVM)` and have a strongly-typed way of referring to your property names.