# Insert Model object effectively using entity framwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF MVVM Application.  I have a Customer Model which is generated by an entity framework (Database first approach) and one `CustomerViewModel` where I created an instance of a Customer Model and used Model members inside the `ViewModel` property get and set.

Here is my Customer Model:

```
public partial class TblCustomer
{
    public TblCustomer()
    {
        this.TblSalesInvoices = new HashSet<TblSalesInvoice>();
        this.TblSalesOrders = new HashSet<TblSalesOrder>();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }  //Primary key Identity
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual TblUser TblUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblSalesInvoice> TblSalesInvoices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblSalesOrder> TblSalesOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `CustomerViewModel`:

```
    private TblCustomer_customerModel;
    public TblCustomer CustomerModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _customerModel?? (_customerModel= new TblCustomer());
        }
        set { _customerModel= value; }
    }

    #region Bindable Properties

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return CustomerModel.CustomerName;
        }
        set
        {
            CustomerModel.CustomerName= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CustomerName");
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return CustomerModel.Email;
        }
        set
        {
            CustomerModel.Email = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }

    private ICommand _saveCommand;
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_saveCommand == null)
            {
                _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Save());
            }
            return _saveCommand;
        }
    }
   #Endregion Bindable Properties


    private void SaveCustomer()
    {
        using(var context=new R_MaizeEntities())
        {
            context.TblCustomers.Add(CustomerModel);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Is this a correct way create a Model class instance in `ViewModel` class and set and get model class members inside the `ViewModel` Property get and set?  By doing so, does the `ViewModel` class have a dependency on the `Model` class?  Is there any other efficient way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Entity

> ```
> public partial class TblCustomer
> ```

The `Tbl` prefix belongs in the database, *if it belongs anywhere at all*. You have plenty of ways with Entity Framework, to map an entity type to a specific table, there's no need to carry database design mistakes into the code. Also entity types don't need to be `partial`.

One way could be to use annotations:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("TblCustomer")]
public class Customer
{
}
```

Another way could be to use the *fluent API* in the `OnModelCreating` method override of your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("TblCustomer");
}
```

The most verbose way would be to create an `EntityTypeConfiguration` class:

```
public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        ToTable("TblCustomer");
    }
}
```

And then to load that configuration into the model builder:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
}
```

You'll probably want to prefer *convention over configuration*, so simple data annotations should do the trick.

---

This comment:

> ```
> public int CustomerId { get; set; }  //Primary key Identity
> ```

Doesn't need to exist. Entity Framework understands `[EntityName]Id` as your primary key (also just `Id` works), *by convention* - the mapping is *automagic*.

If you prefer it to be explicit (/*by configuration*) you can, again, use data annotations:

```
[Key()]
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
```

..or configure it in *OnModelCreating*:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("TblCustomer");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(e => e.CustomerId);
}
```

..or configure it in an `EntityTypeConfiguration` class:

```
public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.CustomerId);
        ToTable("TblCustomer");
    }
}
```

And then to load that configuration into the model builder:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
}
```

The comment doesn't add anything new, and at worst it could be just a lie (because if you're using configurations *the entity type itself doesn't know which property is a key*). I'd just remove it.

---

#### ViewModel

> ```
> #region Bindable Properties
> ```

Don't. *Any property that is `public` is bindable*. This comment/region can only turn into an eventual lie. Remove it.

---

> ```
> using(var context=new R_MaizeEntities())
> ```

`R_MaizeEntities` is an awful name for a type. Syntax highlighting doesn't even pick it up as a C# type name, that's a sign. I don't know what the `R_` stands for, and I'm pretty sure it's meaningless - the type should be named `MaizeEntities` or `MaizeContext`.

One problem you have in your *ViewModel*, is that you can't test it without hitting the database and *actually* performing a save: your *ViewModel* is *strongly coupled* with **everything** you're `new`ing up in that class.

Think of it: anything the *ViewModel* is `new`ing up, is a *dependency*. If it makes sense for the *ViewModel* to be tightly coupled with specific commands, being tightly coupled with a specific data context makes your code pretty much untestable.

I would either constructor-inject the context (as an *abstraction*), or constructor-inject a context *factory* (as an *abstract factory*) whose job would be to instantiate a data context - and unit tests can inject a stub factory that instantiates a mock context for testing purposes.

---

The `CustomerName` property should be using `_customerModel` - it being `null` wouldn't result in a `NullReferenceException` at runtime, only as a silent binding error that you wouldn't be getting if `_customerModel` was constructor-injected instead of being `new`'d up in the property getter.

---

I think there might be a bug here:

```
_saveCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Save());
```

Looks like the command should be calling the `SaveCustomer()` method. Or there's a `Save()` method somewhere else?

---

`RaisePropertyChanged` doesn't follow naming conventions: if the method does what it says it does, it should be named `OnPropertyChanged`.

Raising a `PropertyChanged` event is surely something that's common to all your *ViewModel* classes. Why not write a `ViewModelBase` abstract class, and shove the property-changing logic in there? [See this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/30769/23788) for some ideas, more specifically about referring to property names in a strongly-typed manner.

Comment: very useful,I have a doubt ,if I use CustomerModel as constructor injected,I fill all the CustomerModel properties and insert that into my database,then what should I do to insert another record ,Is to clear all the customerModel properties or just set it to null then reInstantiate it what is the best approach ?